# Finding all components that use taxonomy keyword or keyword below it in taxonomy tree

Tags: broker, taxonomy

We are tagging our components with 1 keyword from a taxonomy tree, thereby indicating its "location" in the taxonomy tree. Now in the backend, given a taxonomy key, I want to query the broker for all components that either use that specific keyword, or a keyword lower in the taxonomy than the specified keyword. I tried to use a CategorizationCriteria, first retrieving all keywords below the given keyword, and then passing those into CategorizationCriteria, but this seems to only find components that have ALL specified keywords, while I need components that use ANY of those keywords. 
What would be the way to go about this?

Comment: I did it using a TaxonomyKeywordCriteria, specifying true to indicate to include keyword branches, and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Go ahead and convert your comment to an answer so it can be marked as "correct"